# Media Player Classic video size zoom incorrect

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I am using latest version MPCHC latest version.

As the screenshot below, the video in MPCHC seem goes outside of the screen.
But VLC play properly.

I just try download a new copy of MPCHC, unzip and play, it is same.

So what setting can i adjust to play the video correct?

[image: VLC]

[image: MPCHC]

Comment: in view/video frame there is an array of settings that should be able to adjust for that. Also in Pan&Scan there are ways to adjust the picture size, that does not work for all codec types. size and panning, Hold Ctrl and using the number keypad is a great way to do size with shotrcut keys. (dependant on how your shorcut keys are set)

Comment: @Psycogeek, i try it, also reset the pan/scan settings, it is same. The funny things is i change the DirectShow video render from EVR custom to VMR9, it is work! but i need EVR Custom to support DXVA.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the Pan&Scan finetuning options. The option above (Video Image) has a submenu where 'touch windows from inside' should be selected.

This makes sure that you see 100% of the video, with some black borders if necessary to adapt to your screen.